# Unit testing with cloud storage

Tags: unit-testing, google-app-engine

I was writing some unit test to cover some uploading and reading files from GCS (Google Cloud Storage).

But apparently the files are not stored locally but uploaded, as I get the following error:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><Error><Code>AuthenticationRequired</Code><Message>Authentication required.</Message></Error>

at com.google.appengine.tools.cloudstorage.RetryHelper.doRetry(RetryHelper.java:120)
at com.google.appengine.tools.cloudstorage.RetryHelper.runWithRetries(RetryHelper.java:166)
at com.google.appengine.tools.cloudstorage.RetryHelper.runWithRetries(RetryHelper.java:156)
at com.google.appengine.tools.cloudstorage.GcsServiceImpl.createOrReplace(GcsServiceImpl.java:70)
```

The unit test looks something like this:

```
private final LocalServiceTestHelper helper = new LocalServiceTestHelper(
        new LocalDatastoreServiceTestConfig().setDefaultHighRepJobPolicyUnappliedJobPercentage(1).setNoStorage(true),
        new LocalCapabilitiesServiceTestConfig(),
        new LocalBlobstoreServiceTestConfig(),
        new LocalImagesServiceTestConfig()
    );

    @Before
    public void setUp() {

        helper.setUp();
    }

    @After
    public void tearDown() {

        helper.tearDown();
    }

    @Test
    public void someTest() { ... }
```

What is the correct way to locally run GCS in unit tests?

Answer (score 0):

What version of the GCS client are you using? Are the GCS tests working for you (e.g. https://code.google.com/p/appengine-gcs-client/source/browse/trunk/java/src/test/java/com/google/appengine/tools/cloudstorage/GcsServiceTest.java) as they also depend on local storage and last checked working fine.

Comment: Have not tried those tests, but found out that if I run test with maven they work. If I run them in Idea they fail with the given error.

Answer (score -1):

I was able to get the Python unit tests to work, although not currently on Master, I had to used commit 8f196d4. The best example of using a local stub is in the cloudstorage_test in the repository, the relevant part is below:

https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-gcs-client/blob/master/python/test/cloudstorage_test.py

See the following Github issue about avoiding a problematic commit:

https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-gcs-client/issues/21

```
class CloudStorageTest(unittest.TestCase):
  """Test for cloudstorage."""

  def setUp(self):
    self.testbed = testbed.Testbed()
    self.testbed.activate()
    self.testbed.init_app_identity_stub()
    self.testbed.init_blobstore_stub()
    self.testbed.init_datastore_v3_stub()
    self.testbed.init_memcache_stub()
    self.testbed.init_urlfetch_stub()
    cloudstorage.set_default_retry_params(None)

  def tearDown(self):
    self.testbed.deactivate()

  def testReadEntireFile(self):
    f = cloudstorage.open(TESTFILE, 'w')
    f.write('abcde')
    f.close()

    f = cloudstorage.open(TESTFILE, read_buffer_size=1)
    self.assertEqual('abcde', f.read())
    f.close()

    f = cloudstorage.open(TESTFILE)
    self.assertEqual('abcde', f.read(8))
    f.close()
```